# Theoretically, can the interconnection between a USB Printer and a PC be called as a network?

Tags: network

The three conditions that must be fulfilled in order for a system working to be called a network are:

1. The existence of data communication
2. A minimum of two devices that are connected through said network
3. Communication(s) that follow a standard protocol

After some Googling, I've found out that USB actually has its own protocols: [here](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb3.shtml) and [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/208611/is-there-an-actual-usb-communication-protocol/). The second condition is obviously fulfilled (my PC and the printer). However, what about the first one?

I recall that the definition of data communication implicitly means that there is one device that is requesting data (receiver) and hence, the other device would send said data (source). After thinking through, it's not really the printer that **is actually asking for data**, it's my PC that is **instructing the printer to receive said data and process it**. So my question is, can the interconnection between a PC and a USB-connected printer be called a network?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers and consumer-grade devices are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "network" assumes the (potential) existence of multiple networked nodes that can all talk to each other. The conditions you list are not sufficient.

USB is a hierarchical, host-device protocol stack with a single host and multiple devices which cannot talk to each other. All communication is controlled by the host. Hence it's not a network.